# I really do not know why my ouput file gives strange arrangement in linux

Tags: col

I really do not know why my output file gives strange arrangement.

I am using the awk command to print columns of a file, e.g 
`awk '{print $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $2, $1}' inputfile > outputfile`.

I however do not have an output file of 5 columns in that order. instead i have output file in this order: column1, column2, column6, column7.

When I viewed the output file in excel:

[image]

I realized the file is in the order below:

```
row1: column3, column4, column5, column6, column7
row2:          column1, column2
```

[image] 
[image]

Can anyone help with what I am probably doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Excel may show CSV (comma separated values) files incorrectly. Also the command `awk '{print $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $2, $1}'` in fact print variables `$1, $2` etc. but where comes the values of the vars?

Comment: i have an original file that contains 7 columns but would like to rearrange it, e.g $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $2, $1}. when i used the awk command, i got that strange arrangement (second image), my original file is space separated file

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question. apparently, there is a carriage-return character (^M) in my file, which marks an end-of-line, and affects arrangement of my file. so i removed the carriage-return-character in Vim by typing :%s/^M/

(Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to insert that ^M.). save and quit by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>